# Hide window when creating new process

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am starting a new process with the following code:

```
Process n;
n = Process.Start("D:\\Update");
```

When the process starts, it is visible on the desktop. Is there any way to ensure that the new process will start in the background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
   FileName = "Myapplication.exe",
   WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
};

Process process = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo };

process.Start();
```

you can pass any arguments using the code below

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a ipaddress -L;" //just an example
```

Comment: what about if i need to add like args to the exe? like "-console map " in games.

Comment: @user876239 take a look at the various members of ProcesstartInfo and you'll find one for arguments